# FilesMatch - how to make every file downloadable attachment?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following FilesMatch directive in my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp4|pdf)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

I cannot find the right expression to have **every** single file to be downloadable - and I don't want to add all the extensions ...

How can I make this work for all files?

Comment: Does it mean the regex should match anything? Use `".+"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(mp4|pdf)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

But if you mean to allow all file extension then you can try this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.+$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

> to have **every** single file to be downloadable

It feels like there must be some other requirement, but to have "every single file downloadable", just remove the `<FilesMatch>` wrapper:

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```